# Responsive grid with horizontal and vertical elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP90V.png

I'm not actually sure if this is possible, I suspect it may not be, or that a Javascript library may be needed to accomplish this.

What I am trying to do is build out a responsive gallery that has both vertical and horizontal elements that tetris themselves together. What I've discovered is that while you can get the elements to look good at one specific screen size, as soon as you alter the viewport width you end up with 'holes' in the layout.

Can anybody think of a way to get the content to flow on a page in a way that it will be both responsive and yet not leave gaps in the content? I'm using Bootstrap 4 and I am happy to use whatever JS or CSS may be needed to accomplish this.

Comment: You can explore CSS grid --> https://gridbyexample.com/examples/

Comment: Hi not really sure why this is getting such a poor response, I think it was a valid question. I've tried using Grid and I haven't been able to figure out a way to get what I originally asked, which was a self-tetris-ing responsive grid. I'm guessing from the reaction to this post that it's not actually possible.

Comment: Hi Brian, questions will get a much better response if they include code, in this case the HTML you are working with and any CSS you have tried. The layout in your image could be made a number of ways. It is a little unclear as to what you mean by 'tetris' themselves - we could visualise this better with images at different screen widths. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the structure similar to yours, it's a bit messy as had to use classes and yes it's Bootstrap class (`col-12` <- this is similar to `col-xs-12` which is for <576px)

You can add your required sized and structure it accordingly.

Let me know if you don't understand something.

```css
.outer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.top {
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container outer">
  <div class="row top">
    <div class="col-3" style="border:1px solid black;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12" style="border:1px solid black; height:125px;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-12" style="border:1px solid black; height:125px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-6" style="border:1px solid black;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6" style="border:1px solid black; height:125px;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6" style="border:1px solid black; height:125px;">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12" style="border:1px solid black; height:125px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-3" style="border:1px solid black;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12" style="border:1px solid black; height:250px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row top">

    <div class="col-3" style="border:1px solid black;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12" style="border:1px solid black; height:250px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-3" style="border:1px solid black;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12" style="border:1px solid black; height:125px;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-12" style="border:1px solid black; height:125px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-3" style="border:1px solid black;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12" style="border:1px solid black; height:125px;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-12" style="border:1px solid black; height:125px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-3" style="border:1px solid black;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12" style="border:1px solid black; height:125px;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-12" style="border:1px solid black; height:125px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dhaval that is quite impressive, I'm not sure it will actually work and it's (aside from the single breakpoint) not really responsive, though it is looking like the layout I want isn't technically possible to implement in a fully responsive way. I'd like to play around with it using my actual code to see if I can make it work, but for some reason the layout breaks completely when you try and use it with Bootstrap 4. Any idea why? The classes you've used are the same in 4 as far as I know.

Comment: absolutely they work the same but they have different name, let me check

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but that code is no longer responsive at all

Comment: Show me a picture of how you want it to look.